# Convert Double Matrix To HSV in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, hsv

I have a double matrix ​​in matlab and I want to convert it to an HSV image where supposedly similar double values ​​will appear with same color. I already converted to RGB with mat2gray but I want to to convert directly from double matrix to hsv image. Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You're asking if you can do what `image` and `imagesc` do.  Yes, you can. You just need to interpolate into the 'hsv' colormap.  The following code snippet demonstrates how to do this. It assumes your values are scaled between 0 and 1; you can easily change that though.

```
im = [0 .5 1; .7 .6 .2; .9 .3 .4];
cm = colormap('hsv');
cdata = interp1(linspace(0,1,length(cm)),cm,im);
figure;image(cdata)
```

`cdata` will be a (row x col x 3) matrix, you can use `image` directly to see it, or do whatever else you need to from there.